# Draw discontinued field using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a discontinued field as shown in the attached picture, but I don't know how can i do it using Tikz. Any idea ?
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[dashed,very thick] (-1.0,4.0) -- ++(0,-4) -- ++(2,0) -- ++(0,4);
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (-1.0,0.0) rectangle (1.0,0.5);
            \foreach \y in {0.0,0.1,...,0.5}{
                \foreach \x in {-1.0,-0.9,...,1.0}{
                    \pgfmathsetmacro\y{ 0.1*cos( rand r ) + \y };
                    \pgfmathsetmacro\x{ 0.1*cos( rand r ) + \x };
                    \fill[gray] (\x,\y) circle[ radius=1pt ];
                }
            }
    \end{scope}
    \draw[very thick] (-1.0,0.0) rectangle (1.0,0.5);
    \draw[{latex}-{latex}](-1.01,0.6)  -- (0.99,0.6) node[midway, above]{$d$};
    \draw[|<->|](4.2,0)--(4.2,-1.)node[midway,right]{$\lambda$};
    % fields
    \foreach \y in {-1.0,-0.,...,3}{
        \draw[](-4,\y) -- (4,\y);
        \foreach \x in {-3,-2,-0.5,0.5,2,3}{
            \draw[-{latex}, thick](\x,\y) -- ++(0,0.4);
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and turn your code fragment into something we can compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: broken paths]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[dashed,very thick] (-1,4) -- ++(0,-4) -- ++(2,0) -- ++(0,4);
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (-1,0) rectangle (1,0.5);
    \foreach \y in {0.0,0.1,...,0.5}{
      \foreach \x in {-1.0,-0.9,...,1.0}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\y{ 0.1*cos( rand r ) + \y };
        \pgfmathsetmacro\x{ 0.1*cos( rand r ) + \x };
        \fill[gray] (\x,\y) circle[ radius=1pt ];
      }
    }
  \end{scope}
  \draw[very thick] (-1,0) rectangle (1,0.5);
  \draw[{latex}-{latex}](-1.01,0.6)  -- (0.99,0.6) node[midway, above]{$d$};
  \draw[|<->|](4.2,0)--(4.2,-1.)node[midway,right]{$\lambda$};
  % fields
  \foreach \y in {-1,...,3}{
    \ifnum\y>0
      \draw (-4,\y) -- (-.5,\y) -- ++({.125*\y},{-.125*\y}) coordinate [midway] (al\y) ++({1-(.25*\y)},0) -- ++({.125*\y},{.125*\y}) coordinate [midway] (ar\y) -- (4,\y);
      \draw [-latex, thick] (al\y) -- ++(45:.4);
      \draw [-latex, thick] (ar\y) -- ++(135:.4);
    \else
      \draw[](-4,\y) -- (4,\y);
      \foreach \x in {-0.5,0.5} \draw[-{latex}, thick](\x,\y) -- ++(0,0.4);
    \fi
    \foreach \x in {-3,-2,2,3}{
      \draw[-{latex}, thick](\x,\y) -- ++(0,0.4);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```